# Entity Framework : implemeting very simple association scenario

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I want to implement the below mentioned problem in Entity Framework.

I have 2 tables( below are their simplified versions)

items table

```
itemId,itemName
```

tags table

```
tagId,tagName
```

- my logic is, an item can have more than one tag and a tag can have more than one item related to it, so I have added many to many relation (please correct me here, if I am wrong)
- I have created model (edmx file) and database from it.
- I have written code for adding data to my sample tables, and its working fine. Below is sample data

  ```
  itemId  itemName  ---items table
     1   |  fish
     2   |  cell phone

  tagId    tagName ------tags table
     1   |  eatable
     2   |  electronics
     3   |  non veg
  ```

I need to know how to write these 3 queries

1. add relation between tag and item e.g. add tags "eatables", "nonveg" to item "fish"
2. get all tags related to an item (eg: fish)
3. get all tags not related to an item (eg: fish)

Comment: "eatable" should really be "edible" in proper English.

Answer (score 1):

If your association is in place with normal naming (an EDMX diagram in your question would help) ...

Q 1.

```
Tag tag = ...  // probably load from database or create if necessary
Item item = ...
item.Tags.Add(tag);
```

Q 2.

```
var tags = item.Tags;
```

Q 3.a All tags not related to ANY item

```
var unrelatedTags = context.Tags.Where(tag => tag.Items.Count() > 0);
```

Q 3.b All tags not related to a specific item

```
var unrelatedTags = context.Tags.Except(item.Tags);
```

Comment: query 2 didnt work, in query 3 (ie for unrelated tags): iam looking for tags that are not related to a particular item. eg: in case "fish" i want it to return "electronics" as its the only tag out of all tags which is not related to fish

Comment: Added 3b for a specific item.  So what didn't work on Q2? How can Q1 work if Q2 doesn't for you?  They use the same .Tags property.

Comment: in q2 iam looking for all tags that are related to an item. in case of fish it should return eatable and non veg. i found the way : item.Tags is okie , but while writting query for item we have to incldue tag like:: var item= _context.items.include("tags").first(i=>i.name="fish"), now item.tags, is correct. iam still looking for third query.